# How can an installation of Ubuntu be repaired?

Tags: login, data-recovery

I am using a version of Ubuntu 14.04 with an encrypted disk, and I ran into problems after updating about a month or so ago. After the installation I can successfully mount the encrypted disk and get to the login screen, but there's no background image and attempts to login seem unsuccessful.

There's a brief error message that pops up before the background becomes "garbled" and I'm sent back to the login. I have files in my documents (on the encrypted disk) that I need to recover, but I have no idea how to fix this (first-time Ubuntu user).

I have a working Ubuntu disk if that helps.  If anyone has an idea of how to fix this without losing my personal files, or knows what's going on, help is appreciated.

Comment: As long you know the pass-phrase for the encrypted disk or user directory you should be able to boot up on a live USB or other Ubuntu install and mount the drive/directory to read it. If you don't have the passphrase you might not be able to recover your data. but maybe other users have ideas how you can tackle that situation since you're able to mount the encrypted disk, it might be simply that your user directory is encrypted too and does not get properly decrypted.

Comment: I would switch to a tty (eg. ctrl+alt+f4) and try logging in that way. If you can login there you can view (`ls`) & make yourself happy that your data is there and accessible), if it fails you hopefully will get more information on why.  If your disk is full (`df -hi` if you can login) the gui will appear to login then logout as it can't create files it needs for gui operation; so it maybe something as simple as disk-full.

Comment: What does the "brief error message" say? Please be as accurate as possible. Error messages are important.

Comment: If you use encryption, backups are ESSENTIAL. The entire purpose of encryption is to deny access to data, and failing toward denial. You are experiencing one of those failures.